# If I made chocolates filled with a shop-bought fruit preserve or jam, how long will it last?

Tags: food-safety

If I made chocolates filled with fruit the product, would the use by date of the original jar of preserve still count or would the homemade chocolates have to be used up in a couple of days?  If the jar's use by date still applied, how can the homemade chocolates' same fruit filling be made to last as long as the chocolate?

Answer (score 1):

The use by date on the jar assumes that it is refrigerated after opening. So you have to keep them in the fridge, or eat them soon.